# Why zig-zag in time series plot visualisation in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Simple imports of pandas and altair.

```
#"https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/mean-bmi-(kg-m-)-(crude-estimate)")

df = pd.read_csv("obesity_WHO.csv")
df_cropped = df.loc[:, ["Location", "Period", "FactValueNumericHigh"]]
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200
print(df_cropped[df_cropped['Location'].str.contains("United")]['Location'])

# Sort dataframe by "Period"
df_cropped = df_cropped.sort_values("Period")

# Define a selection for the dropdown
country = alt.selection_single(
    name="Location",
    fields=["Location"],
    init={"Location": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"},  # Assuming "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" is a valid country in your dataframe
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=list(df_cropped['Location'].unique()))  # Creating a dropdown for country selection
)

# Define a base chart
base = alt.Chart(df_cropped).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X("Period:O"),
    alt.Y("FactValueNumericHigh:Q"),
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

# Define a highlight chart that will only include data for the selected country
highlight = alt.Chart(df_cropped).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("Period:O"),
    alt.Y("FactValueNumericHigh:Q"),
    color=alt.value('orange')
).transform_filter(
    country
).interactive()

# Overlay the highlight chart on top of the base chart
chart = alt.layer(base, highlight).add_selection(country)

chart.configure_view(fill="#fff").properties(width=600, height=300)
```

I want to use Altair so there is a selector for different countries. Why the zig-zag?

Confused as to why output looks like this: There is only one year for each datapoint row.

[image]

(Ignore the axis formatting)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572704/how-to-make-an-interactive-plot-in-pandas-and-altair/76576090#76576090

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an interactive plot in pandas and altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572704/how-to-make-an-interactive-plot-in-pandas-and-altair)