# How to make an interactive plot in pandas and altair

Tags: pandas, visualization, altair

Simple imports of pandas and altair. Why the shape of the plot when one datapoint by each row?

```
#"https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/mean-bmi-(kg-m-)-(crude-estimate)")

df = pd.read_csv("obesity_WHO.csv")
df_cropped = df.loc[:, ["Location", "Period", "FactValueNumericHigh"]]
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200
print(df_cropped[df_cropped['Location'].str.contains("United")]['Location'])

# Sort dataframe by "Period"
df_cropped = df_cropped.sort_values("Period")

# Define a selection for the dropdown
country = alt.selection_single(
    name="Location",
    fields=["Location"],
    init={"Location": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"},  # Assuming "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" is a valid country in your dataframe
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=list(df_cropped['Location'].unique()))  # Creating a dropdown for country selection
)

# Define a base chart
base = alt.Chart(df_cropped).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X("Period:O"),
    alt.Y("FactValueNumericHigh:Q"),
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

# Define a highlight chart that will only include data for the selected country
highlight = alt.Chart(df_cropped).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("Period:O"),
    alt.Y("FactValueNumericHigh:Q"),
    color=alt.value('orange')
).transform_filter(
    country
).interactive()

# Overlay the highlight chart on top of the base chart
chart = alt.layer(base, highlight).add_selection(country)

chart.configure_view(fill="#fff").properties(width=600, height=300)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have multiple data points per year for the same country and Altair connects them with a line:

[image]

If you want a single line location per year, you need to either get rid of the additoinal data points or aggregate them, e.g using an average via `alt.Y("mean(FactValueNumericHigh)")`

[image]

This is how many points you have for each year for the same location:

[image]